# Calibrating a battery

Tags: windows-7, windows, battery, battery-life

I have a laptop and I would like to know how to calibrate my battery.

Answer (score 4):

There are usually three ways of proceeding, and it depends entirely on model and what is available to you:

1. If your laptop has a manufacturer provided power utility, take a look in that for a calibrate button.
2. If that fails, look in the BIOS for a calibrate button.
3. If both of those fail, simply charge the battery to maximum and then go in to the BIOS and unplug. Do a full discharge and this should calibrate the battery. I always say do it in the BIOS as this makes sure there is nothing running/active that can be damaged by a forced shutdown.

Comment: You should probably disable any power settings that might hibernate/sleep the computer when battery-power drops below a certain level.

Comment: @Nifle If you go into the BIOS, this isn't needed.